# need an extra column with an edit and delete button that takes the ID from each row and passes it to an edit and delete function in the

Tags: angular, frontend, backend

need an extra column with an edit and delete button that takes the ID from each row and passes it to an edit and delete function in the .ts file.

How does one go about doing this?

```
<!-- Container-fluid starts-->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5>Page Details</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="custom-datatable">
                        
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <ngx-datatable class="bootstrap" [rows]="branches" [columnMode]="'force'" [headerHeight]="50"
                            [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="'auto'" [limit]="5" [selected]="selected"
                            [selectionType]="'checkbox'" [selectAllRowsOnPage]="false" (select)='onSelect($event)'>
                            <ngx-datatable-column [width]="30" [sortable]="false" [canAutoResize]="false"
                                [draggable]="false" [resizeable]="false" [headerCheckboxable]="true"
                                [checkboxable]="true">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primery">Delete</button>
                            </ngx-datatable-column>
                            <ngx-datatable-column name="name"></ngx-datatable-column>
                            <ngx-datatable-column name="location"></ngx-datatable-column>
                            <ngx-datatable-column prop="storeId"></ngx-datatable-column>
                            <ngx-datatable-column prop="storeId"></ngx-datatable-column>
                            
                        </ngx-datatable>
                        
                        
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Container-fluid Ends-->
```